# writing from scratch or using CMS for heavy database use website

Tags: asp.net, database, wordpress, drupal, optimization

we want to build a website that have some forms (including image attachments, info, etc…) online payments, tracking system, and other features that I may add later.

The number of users using the site is estimated to be maybe more than 50,000.

I'm using Wordpress to develop regular websites, but I'm afraid to use it in this project because I don't know how optimized is WordPress for high database usage (and page rendering, bandwidth usage, and …)

My options (those that I know) are:

- WordPress
- Drupal
- Pressflow
- Agility CMS
- Writing PHP/MySQL code from scratch (or using a framework)

I know it maybe unrelated, but how good is to use ASP.net instead of these options?

Comment: wwe is using drupal http://www.lullabot.com/articles/wwe-lullabot-tag-team-drupal-relaunch

Comment: drupal might be a good option, as it is very easy to extend and designed for high traffic and large websites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. If you are most comfortable with PHP (the scripting language behind Wordpress and Drupal), you'll most likely be more comfortable making the step to Drupal. Pressflow is just a fork of Drupal optimized for particular needs (and there are other forks of it -- all of them are really just Drupal and are often the basis for various Drupal distributions).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has a lot of capable options to do this. The most common ones (at least in my world), are Kentico, Umbraco, and DotNetNuke. There are a ton of others.

You'll find lots of capable CMS systems to work with no matter what language you're looking at. Use what you're most comfortable working with.